# value is updated in DB with ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess after serializing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, strong-parameters

I am trying to update a columns value to a hash in database. The column in database is text.

In model i have,

```
serialize :order_info
```

In controller i have update action

```
  def update
    Order.update_order_details(update_params, params[:order_info])
    head :no_content
  end
```

I am not doing strong parameters for order_info because order_info is an arbitrary hash and after doing research, strong params doesnt support an arbitrary hash

The value that i am trying to pass is like below

```
"order_info": {
    "orders": [
        {
            "test": "AAAA"
        }
    ], 
"detail": "BBBB",
"type": "CCCC"
}
```

But when i try to update the value it gets updated in database like

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess   comments:   - !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess     test: AAAA   detail: BBBB   type: CCCC permitted: false
```

serialize is an instance of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess so i am guessing thats why its in the value. How can i get rid of the extra stuff and just update the hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to unwrap all the `ActionController::Parameters` stuff from `params[:order_info]` without any filtering then the easiest thing to do is call `to_unsafe_h` (or its alias `to_unsafe_hash`):

```
hash = params[:order_info].to_unsafe_h
```

In Rails4 that should give you a plain old `Hash` in `hash` but AFAIK Rails5 will give you an `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` so you might want to add a `to_h` call:

```
hash = params[:order_info].to_unsafe_h.to_h
```

The `to_h` call won't do anything in Rails4 but will give you one less thing to worry about when you upgrade to Rails5.

Then your update call:

```
Order.update_order_details(
  update_params,
  params[:order_info].to_unsafe_h.to_h # <-------- Extra DWIM method calls added
)
```

should give you the YAML in the database that you're looking for:

```
"---\n:order_info:\n  :orders:\n  - :test: AAAA\n  :detail: BBBB\n  :type: CCCC\n"
```

You might want to throw in a `deep_stringify_keys` call too:

```
params[:order_info].to_unsafe_h.to_h.deep_stringify_keys
```

depending on what sort of keys you want in your YAMLizied Hash.

Comment: Thank you so much. I also tried .to_unsafe_h.deep_symbolize_keys but your answer is much better. you saved my day tomorrow :)